# Sort entries by date mixing two post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, sort

I'm trying to build a wp_query for two post types (post and product. The second is a woocommerce custom post type). The goal is to get a list of posts sorted by date. Something like this:

```
 - Post 3.    (april, 3)
 - Post 2.    (march, 15)
 - Product 2. (february, 10)
 - Post 1.    (january, 4)
 - Product 1. (january, 1)
```

I have this arguments:

```
$args = array (
  'post_type'         => array( 'product', 'post' ),
  'nopaging'          => true,
  'meta_key'          => '_featured',
  'meta_value'        => 'yes',
  'orderby'           => 'date',
  'order'             => 'desc',
);
```

But it returns a separated lists of post types:

```
 - Post 3.    (april, 3)
 - Post 2.    (march, 15)
 - Post 1.    (january, 4)

 - Product 2. (february, 10)
 - Product 1. (january, 1)
```

How can I get a unique list mixing the two post types? (as in the first example)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Have you tried to `print_r( $query->request );` after creating your new `WP_Query` object? That should give you the raw SQL.

Comment: It returs this: SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_featured' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'yes' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product', 'post') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: That looks fine. Could you check the post_date fields directly in your database? Maybe the products were published a few years ago :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This WP is in local development, with new entries that I can delete or add to try it. I think this is a normal behavior for this query: to list post ordered by date and, then, to list products ordered by date. In order to be completely clear, I ask for a method to get a unique list ordered by date, regardless of the post type (maybe with wp_query arguments or maybe rearranging this wp_query results).

Comment: Given your query, it should do exactly what you are asking. Unless you or some plugin is doing something strange and rearranging the results manually via some `WP_Query` filter, then my guess is that the dates in the database are incorrect. Try and run the query directly in MySQL and see what order you get.

Comment: Ok! I will try it

Comment: Ok, This is what I did: 1) Deploy it to staging with four entries (2 products and 2 posts) http://stage.lolafonseca.com/ 2) ask MySQL: http://pastebin.com/7GY5nqPW There is a weird thing here. In the manual query there are no posts returned, just products

Comment: Can you also show the full source of the template file you're using? It sounds like the two posts are returned by the main WordPress loop, and the two products are appended as part of your secondary loop. Perhaps you're missing the _featured meta key on your posts?

Comment: Of course, here it is: http://pastebin.com/KMfj2kea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43353/discussion-between-kovshenin-and-aitor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem seems to be that posts was marked as sticky, not featured, and prepend other posts. So, I have featured products and sticky posts. I need to add featured meta key to posts and remove sticky flag.

Thank you very much Kovshenin